# Connecting pgAdmin and PostgreSQL to Docker: container shows an empty database

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, pgadmin

I need help with Connecting pgAdmin and Postgres to the Docker container.
I run everything locally on my Mac, previously I had already installed Postgres there using homebrew, that’s why I use port 5431:5432.
Following the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCAIVe9N0ow&list=PL3MmuxUbc_hJed7dXYoJw8DoCuVHhGEQb&ab_channel=DataTalksClub%E2%AC%9B) “Connecting pgAdmin and Postgres”  at minute 6:09 I make these steps and get an empty database, though it was visible before all of these manipulations:
After I run:

```
docker run -it \\
  -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="admin@admin.com" \\
  -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="root" \\
  -p 8080:80 \\
  dpage/pgadmin4
```

I press control + C

1. Then I stop the container with postgres (docker stop containerID)
2. Creating a network
3. Running this:

```
docker run -it \\
  -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \\
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \\
  -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \\
  -v $(pwd)/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgres/data \\
  -p 5431:5432 \\
  --network=pg-network \\
  --name pg-database \\
  postgres:13
```

4. Now when we are checking the data, I have an empty database.

```
root@localhost:ny_taxi> select count(1) from yellow_taxi_data;
relation "yellow_taxi_data" does not exist
LINE 1: select count(1) from yellow_taxi_data
```

When I press \d :

```
root@localhost:ny_taxi> \d
+--------+------+------+-------+
| **Schema** | **Name** | **Type** | **Owner** | |
--------+------+------+-------|
+--------+------+------+-------+
```

The database ny_taxi appears to be empty.

The list of all databases with command \l:

```
root@localhost:postgres> \l
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| Name      | Owner | Encoding | Collate    | Ctype      | Access privileges |
|-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------|
| ny_taxi   | root  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | <null>            |
| postgres  | root  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | <null>            |
| template0 | root  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/root           |
|           |       |          |            |            | root=CTc/root     |
| template1 | root  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/root           |
|           |       |          |            |            | root=CTc/root     |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
```

What should I do? What’s the issue? Server?
I am dealing with Docker for the first time.
Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You never describe populating your database.  Why wouldn't it be empty?

Comment: Check if $(pwd)/ny_taxi_postgres_data in your local path contains some data.
And i think in -v option, must be /var/lib/postgresql/data (not /var/lib/postgres/data).
Look : https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the volume is not added to the postgres container.

The default postgresql data directory is `/var/lib/postgresql/data` not `/var/lib/postgres/data` so instead of:

```
docker run -it \\
  -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \\
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \\
  -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \\
  -v $(pwd)/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgres/data \\
  -p 5431:5432 \\
  --network=pg-network \\
  --name pg-database \\
  postgres:13
```

Try

```
docker run -it \\
  -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \\
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \\
  -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \\
  -v $(pwd)/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \\
  -p 5431:5432 \\
  --network=pg-network \\
  --name pg-database \\
  postgres:13
```

To verify your postgres data directory, you can run `SHOW data_directory;` with superuser access or run this query `select setting from pg_settings where name = 'data_directory';`

I hope this helps.